# Protractor - exiting nested for loop if element.getAttribute('class') changes

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am new to protractor, javascript, and async programming in general. I'm having trouble with exiting nested for loops once I've found that a specific element on the page has changed it's class.

Unfortunately I have a flash object on the page I'm automating that I must interact with. I'm using direct mouseMoves and clicks to do so, which I've found is satisfactory.  I want to click in a 10x10 grid pattern until I click on something in the grid that will change the class of another element on the page. Here is my code:

```
var selectSeat = function() {
  var xCoord = 157;
  var yCoord = 57;
  var breakLoop = false;
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++) {
      browser.actions().mouseMove(flashElement, {x: xCoord+(15*i), y: yCoord+(15*j)}).click().perform();
      browser.sleep(500);
      buttonElement.getAttribute('class').then(function(attribute) {
        if(attribute === 'black-button') {
          breakLoop = true;
        }
      })
      if (breakLoop) {
        return;
      }
      }
    }
};
```

I have logged the values of attribute and breakLoop to the console to make sure they were changing as expected, and they are. The problem comes from the 'if (breakLoop) { return; }' block not running, even when breakLoop is true.
I know this has issues due to the asynchronous nature of protractor, but after hours of searching and trying solutions, I can't seem to figure out what my correct solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a famous quote from [here](https://qconnewyork.com/ny2016/ny2016/workshops/async-programming-js-end-loop.html)

> first secret to mastering asynchronous programming:programming without
>   loops. JavaScript's loops can only run synchronously, and cannot be
>   used to repeat asynchronous functions

With that stated, the problem in your code is the condition

```
  if (breakLoop) {
    return;
  }
```

will execute before the getAttribute() comparison and value assignment of breakloop. The protractor-Webdriver commands of first iterations could still be running when you are actually checking for condition in the last iteration

I would suggest something like this. See a beautiful article on the same http://metaduck.com/01-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html

```
var selectSeat = function(callback) {
    var xCoord = 157;
    var yCoord = 57;
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<10; j++) {
            browser.actions().mouseMove(flashElement, {x: xCoord+(15*i), y: yCoord+(15*j)}).click().perform();
            browser.sleep(500);
            buttonElement.getAttribute('class').then(function(attribute) {
                if(attribute === 'black-button') {
                    callback();
                }
            })
           }
    }
};
```

Comment: Like I said before, I'm a novice, so I don't really understand what the callback function is doing.  How does it exit the loop?  I tried using your example and passing in a function that simply returns and that did not work.  I just need more explanation about what your example is doing and I'm sure I can figure it out.